# how to create a simple saving filename dialog in android?

Tags: android, dialog, fragment

i'm trying to create a simple android app for practice exercise. This app is a simple notepad with a main activity, writing activity and reading activity.
Main activity show two button, "write" and "read", that respectively change to writing activity and reading activity.
Now i'm trying to develop writing activity.
Writing activity show one editText for note input and one save button.
after clicking on save button i want that it show me a dialog with one editText for a filename input and two button "save", for saving file and return to main activitiy, and "cancel" for return to writing activity.
My code work for shift to readingactivity and writingactivity but dialog in writingactivity not work.
Can you help me?
i tried with follow code
Best reguards

WRITING ACTIVITY CLASS

```
public class WritingActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_writing);
}

//method onclick save button xml file
public void metodoSalva(View view) {

    SaveDialogFragment DialogFSave = new SaveDialogFragment();
    DialogFSave.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "NoticeDialogFragment");

    Context context = getApplicationContext();

    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.filename_editText);
    String filename = new String(editText.getText().toString() + ".txt");

    File mydir = context.getFilesDir(); //crea una directory privata per l'app in questione nella memoria interna
    File file = new File(mydir, filename); //crea il file nella cartella "mydir" di nome "filename"

    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.write_note);
    String mia_nota = editText.getText().toString();


    FileOutputStream outputStream;

    try {
        outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        outputStream.write(mia_nota.getBytes());
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    finish(); //torna nella main activity terminando l'activity corrente
}

}
```

DIALOG CLASS

```
public class SaveDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {


public SaveDialogFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());

    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();


    builder.setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_save_dialog, null))

            .setPositiveButton(R.string.button_save, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

                }
            });
    return builder.create();
}

}
```

fragment_save_dialog.xml file

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
tools:context="com.html.utente.jammanote.SaveDialogFragment">


<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/menu_fragment" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/filename_editText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:hint="@string/message_insert" />

</FrameLayout>
```

GENYMOTION LOG

```
03-14 15:19:23.755 15636-15636/com.html.utente.jammanote E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                       java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
                                                                           at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3591)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
                                                                           at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586)
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                                                                        Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                           at com.html.utente.jammanote.WritingActivity.metodoSalva(WritingActivity.java:29)
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3586) 
                                                                           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084) 
                                                                           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615) 
                                                                           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92) 
                                                                           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
                                                                           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                                                                           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
                                                                           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
                                                                           at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: is your app crashes? if it is, add your log.

Comment: yes. My app was stopped. where do i find my log? I use genymotion and my samsung galaxy s5 neo for testing app

Comment: Hi, i upgrade question with logFile

Comment: add your log after the app was crashed. it should show you where the error occured (class name and line number).

Comment: Hi, i upgrade question with logFile again